# Как конвертировать XML в JSON на Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, xml

Есть множество онлайн сервисов, подобный этому https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson, и они успешно это делают.

С помощью какой библиотеки можно добиться точно такого же результата?

Answer (score 0):

Скачай пакет xml2json

```
npm install xml2json
```

Код для конвертации:

```js
let xmlParser = require('xml2json');<br>
let xmlString = строка-в-формате-xml;
console.log('JSON после конвертации', xmlParser.toJson(xmlString));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 xml-to-json-stream
```

Я выбрал этот пакет: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-to-json-stream.

Код:

```
 const xmlToJson = require('xml-to-json-stream');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const url = require('url');
 const path = require('path');

 const filePathIn = path.join(__dirname, 'in', 'feed.xml');
 const fileStreamIn = fs.createReadStream(filePathIn);
 const filePathInOut = path.join(__dirname, 'out', 'feed.json');
 const fileStreamInOut = fs.createWriteStream(filePathInOut);

 const parser = xmlToJson();
 const stream = parser.createStream();


 fileStreamIn.pipe(stream).pipe(fileStreamInOut);
```